# Man in the middle after evil twin

Tags: man-in-the-middle, arp-spoofing, evil-twin, ettercap, rogue-ap

I've set up an Evil twin access point using the aircrack suite, what i'm missing is how to complete the man in the middle access point side like the picture shown below, I've been suggested ettercap but I'm not familiar with it.

The goal is:  establish a connection between evil twin the and access point and trick the access point to think the evil twin is the client.

Any help?

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome! It is not clear to me what exactly you are stuck on or what you have already tried. Have you researched any tutorials?

Comment: Hi, I'm stuck on the implementation of the man in the middle because at the moment i do not have enough wireless interfaces, but I also am not sure if the procedure i explained is correct, what I would like to achieve is an evil twin and a man in the middle after that between the two access points